# Compiling Numpy from Source with Intel MKL/Intel C

Tags: python, numpy, intel-mkl

I've been trying to compile numpy from source using Intel MKL and the Intel C/C++ compilers. I have a student license which gives me access to these compilers/MKL. It appears that I built numpy but when I run `numpy.test('full')` I get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1457, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1565, in close
    fp.close()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
EException ignored in: <bound method ZipFile.__del__ of <zipfile.ZipFile object at 0x7fba36cd02e8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1457, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1560, in close
    self.fp.flush()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py:605: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedWriter name='/tmp/tmpgl9796ik.npz'>
  outcome.errors.clear()
EException ignored in: <bound method ZipFile.__del__ of <zipfile.ZipFile object at 0x7fba3727f550>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1457, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1565, in close
    fp.close()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
EEException ignored in: <bound method ZipFile.__del__ of <zipfile.ZipFile object at 0x7fba329a76a0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1457, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1468, in close
    pos1 = self.fp.tell()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tempfile.py", line 399, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
EEEException ignored in: <bound method ZipFile.__del__ of <zipfile.ZipFile object at 0x7fba329a78d0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1457, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1468, in close
    pos1 = self.fp.tell()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
EF....E.EEException ignored in: <bound method ZipFile.__del__ of <zipfile.ZipFile object at 0x7fba329a7fd0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1457, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1565, in close
    fp.close()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
Exception ignored in: <bound method ZipFile.__del__ of <zipfile.ZipFile object at 0x7fba329a73c8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1457, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1565, in close
    fp.close()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
Exception ignored in: <bound method ZipFile.__del__ of <zipfile.ZipFile object at 0x7fba329a7da0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1457, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1565, in close
    fp.close()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
  warnings.warn("Warning: converting a masked element to nan.")
======================================================================
ERROR: test_big_arrays (test_io.TestSavezLoad)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 146, in skipper_func
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 199, in test_big_arrays
    np.savez(tmp, a=a)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 534, in savez
    _savez(file, args, kwds, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 597, in _savez
    format.write_array(fid, np.asanyarray(val))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 562, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
OSError: 2147583648 requested and 2021494704 written

======================================================================
ERROR: test_closing_fid (test_io.TestSavezLoad)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 597, in _savez
    format.write_array(fid, np.asanyarray(val))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 562, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
OSError: first argument must be a string or open file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 282, in test_closing_fid
    np.savez(fp, data='LOVELY LOAD')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 534, in savez
    _savez(file, args, kwds, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 603, in _savez
    fid.close()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

======================================================================
ERROR: test_closing_zipfile_after_load (test_io.TestSavezLoad)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 597, in _savez
    format.write_array(fid, np.asanyarray(val))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 562, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
OSError: first argument must be a string or open file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 309, in test_closing_zipfile_after_load
    np.savez(tmp, lab='place holder')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 534, in savez
    _savez(file, args, kwds, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 603, in _savez
    fid.close()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

======================================================================
ERROR: test_format_2_0 (test_io.TestSavezLoad)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 597, in _savez
    format.write_array(fid, np.asanyarray(val))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 538, in write_array
    version)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 319, in _write_array_header
    fp.write(header)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 166, in test_format_2_0
    self.check_roundtrips(a)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 111, in check_roundtrips
    self.roundtrip(a)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 179, in roundtrip
    RoundtripTest.roundtrip(self, np.savez, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 92, in roundtrip
    save_func(target_file, *arr, **save_kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 534, in savez
    _savez(file, args, kwds, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 603, in _savez
    fid.close()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

======================================================================
ERROR: test_mmap (test_io.TestSavezLoad)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 597, in _savez
    format.write_array(fid, np.asanyarray(val))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 562, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
OSError: first argument must be a string or open file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 92, in roundtrip
    save_func(target_file, *arr, **save_kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 534, in savez
    _savez(file, args, kwds, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 603, in _savez
    fid.close()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 215, in knownfailer
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 152, in test_mmap
    self.roundtrip(a, file_on_disk=True, load_kwds={'mmap_mode': 'r'})
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 179, in roundtrip
    RoundtripTest.roundtrip(self, np.savez, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 107, in roundtrip
    if not isinstance(arr_reloaded, np.lib.npyio.NpzFile):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'arr_reloaded' referenced before assignment

======================================================================
ERROR: test_multiple_arrays (test_io.TestSavezLoad)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 597, in _savez
    format.write_array(fid, np.asanyarray(val))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 562, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
OSError: first argument must be a string or open file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 208, in test_multiple_arrays
    self.roundtrip(a, b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 179, in roundtrip
    RoundtripTest.roundtrip(self, np.savez, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 92, in roundtrip
    save_func(target_file, *arr, **save_kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 534, in savez
    _savez(file, args, kwds, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 603, in _savez
    fid.close()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

======================================================================
ERROR: test_named_arrays (test_io.TestSavezLoad)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 597, in _savez
    format.write_array(fid, np.asanyarray(val))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 562, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
OSError: first argument must be a string or open file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 214, in test_named_arrays
    np.savez(c, file_a=a, file_b=b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 534, in savez
    _savez(file, args, kwds, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 603, in _savez
    fid.close()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

======================================================================
ERROR: test_not_closing_opened_fid (test_io.TestSavezLoad)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 597, in _savez
    format.write_array(fid, np.asanyarray(val))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 562, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
OSError: first argument must be a string or open file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 255, in test_not_closing_opened_fid
    np.savez(fp, data='LOVELY LOAD')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 534, in savez
    _savez(file, args, kwds, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 603, in _savez
    fid.close()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

======================================================================
ERROR: test_record (test_io.TestSavezLoad)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 597, in _savez
    format.write_array(fid, np.asanyarray(val))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 562, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
OSError: first argument must be a string or open file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 159, in test_record
    self.check_roundtrips(a)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 111, in check_roundtrips
    self.roundtrip(a)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 179, in roundtrip
    RoundtripTest.roundtrip(self, np.savez, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 92, in roundtrip
    save_func(target_file, *arr, **save_kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 534, in savez
    _savez(file, args, kwds, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 603, in _savez
    fid.close()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

======================================================================
ERROR: test_io.test_gzip_loadtxt
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 1684, in test_gzip_loadtxt
    os.write(f, s.read())
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

======================================================================
ERROR: test_io.test_npzfile_dict
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 597, in _savez
    format.write_array(fid, np.asanyarray(val))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 562, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
OSError: first argument must be a string or open file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 1708, in test_npzfile_dict
    np.savez(s, x=x, y=y)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 534, in savez
    _savez(file, args, kwds, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 603, in _savez
    fid.close()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

======================================================================
ERROR: test_io.test_load_refcount
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 597, in _savez
    format.write_array(fid, np.asanyarray(val))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 562, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
OSError: first argument must be a string or open file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 1735, in test_load_refcount
    np.savez(f, [1, 2, 3])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 534, in savez
    _savez(file, args, kwds, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 603, in _savez
    fid.close()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

======================================================================
ERROR: test_fromtextfile (test_mrecords.TestMRecordsImport)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/ma/tests/test_mrecords.py", line 489, in test_fromtextfile
    os.write(tmp_fd, fcontent)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

======================================================================
FAIL: test_savez_filename_clashes (test_io.TestSavezLoad)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/tests/test_io.py", line 245, in test_savez_filename_clashes
    raise AssertionError(errors)
AssertionError: [OSError(28, 'No space left on device'), OSError(28, 'No space left on device'), OSError(28, 'No space left on device')]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5762 tests in 122.291s

FAILED (KNOWNFAIL=6, SKIP=17, errors=13, failures=1)
```

Any idea what's going on or where it might be going wrong?

Comment: Just what it says - there is no space left on the device.

Comment: I don't see how that can be the case because I only have a single partition on my hard drive and it is 500 GB.